# How to format values in pie chart on google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, pie-chart

i have a pie chart reporting all my expenses.
I would like to show not the absolute value, but the currency format.
So in this case 10$, 20$ and 37.60$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

format the data range column (source values of pie) to currency

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply
This works only if i don't aggregate values. Every sector is a type of expence (going out, lunch, groceries...) and if i aggregate the values, it gives me the sum, but not the correct formatting. If i do not aggregate them it shows the correct formatting, but for every row of the table, it gives me a different sector.

Comment: it would help if you could share a sample demo sheet recreating this scenario so that we can check it out directly and see what's feasible...

Comment: Here it is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16Vj6kqyIkwR20tsol46uws2ljMcb8d8ovWUVU1A_QK0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: here's one approach. using QUERY() dynamic aggregation is done pre-hand(formula is in cell Y1 and takes into account future data+values added to columns E,F) and fed to the pie chart to retain the currency symbol.